# Unable to create column with maximum length in SYBASE ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

In SQLServer for creating a column of type, say VARBINARY or VARCHAR, we can specify the maximum length as

```
create table sample (c1 varbinary(MAX));
create table sample1 (c1 varchar(MAX));
```

What is the equivalent syntax for SYBASE ?

VARBINARY(MAX) does not seem to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read docs: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00269.1550/html/raxpdb/CIHHGDCE.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
create table sample (c1 Long Binary);
create table sample1 (c1 Long Varchar);
```

Please check with this solution.